# Classical explanation for radiation pressure?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, momentum

With Maxwell's equations, it is known that radiation carries momentum. However, I don't see how light can provide such "longitudinal" momentum if its electric component is perpendicular to its direction of travel, and its magnetic component is supposed to be weak.

I am wondering is there is a more gritty, bottoms-up explanation just in terms of the $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ fields.

Comment: Yes. If the electric field is up/down and the magnetic field is right/left, the electric field induces up/down oscillations of charged particles. Since $\text{up} \times \text{right}$ is forward, the Lorentz force then pushes the particles forward.

Comment: That's very interesting. Just for reference, the answers here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/198026/will-neutral-particles-be-affected-by-em-waves imply that EM waves do not interact with neutral charges, so that makes sense.

Comment: Also, I agree that it's sometimes unintuitive how transverse waves can carry longitudinal momentum. I asked the [same question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257608/momentum-of-transverse-waves-on-a-string) for waves on a string a while back, where it's even trickier.

Comment: @knzhou That first comment is an answer.

Comment: @SpiralRain Objects (like atoms) can be net-neutral but still possessed charged sub-structure, and electromagnetic fields can interact with that sub-structure. Indeed those interactions are responsible for all the ways in which net neutral matter interacts with light (index of refraction, reflectivity, polariod behavior and so on).